# How to order WooCommerce products by attribute term menu order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Let's say there's a product attribute "brand" with the following terms:

- Brand A
- Brand B
- Brand C

Let's also say the menu order of these terms in products > attributes > size have been ordered as such:

- Brand C
- Brand A
- Brand B

How can I sort the products on the shop page by the attribute menu order? So for example:

- Brand C product
- Brand A product
- Brand B product

Assume each product only has a single brand attribute term.

So far I've figured the code will likely involve modifying the query using the `pre_get_posts` hook, but I'm having difficulty customizing the order in such a way.

Comment: Can you show what you've come up with?

Comment: @HowardE Not much...just tried a tax_query but of course all that does is show products with the defined terms. What I really need is a sort of "menu_order" orderby value, but instead of the normal product order, it uses the attribute term order. Or some way to define the order based on the order in a custom-made array would work as well.

Comment: @HowardE Another option could be to save the attributes as meta values and that gives access to the meta_query. That's not desirable though because the postmeta table is already very large on the site. I still don't think that would work, because although I would get access to the meta_key orderby value, there's still only ASC and DESC for order values. So it just goes by alphabetical order rather than any menu order or custom array order.

Answer (score 0):

Since get_terms() is returning the order we have set for our attributes we can get those ids and use them as sorting.

```
//Change taxonomy if you need.
$terms = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'pa_brand','fields' => 'ids'));
```

From there we can use `woocommerce_product_query` to modify our query.

And finaly set the order of our query to be by `term_id` ASC or DESC.

Here is my solution

```
function sort_products_by_brand( $q ) {
        $terms = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'pa_brand','fields' => 'ids'));
        $tax_query = $q->get('tax_query');
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'pa_brand',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => $terms,
        );

        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query);
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'term_id' );
        // $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); // by default is ASC so uncomment if you want DESC.
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'sort_products_by_brand' );
```

Comment: That did change the order, but it does not match the menu order for the terms. I don't believe there is a "term_id" orderby value for WP_Query: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters.

Comment: Yes you are right. Idk why worked at 1st place for me so i guess had some cache idk. Scratch that answer

Comment: should the end of that function have a return $q;  ?

Comment: No but i notice orderby should be set to menu_order instead of term_id as mentioned by Jordan

Answer (score 0):

[Honk31's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/363654/94213) worked well for me. I just had to modify it a little bit.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'jwd_modify_product_query' );
function jwd_modify_product_query($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'pa_brand' );
  }
}



// https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/363654/94213
// Answer by honk31
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'jwd_orderby_tax_clauses', 10, 2 );
function jwd_orderby_tax_clauses($clauses, $wp_query) {
  global $wpdb;
  $orderby = isset($wp_query->query_vars['orderby']) ? $wp_query->query_vars['orderby'] : false;

  if ($orderby && $orderby === 'pa_brand') {
    $clauses['join'] .= <<<SQL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
    SQL;
    $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '{$orderby}' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
    $clauses['groupby'] = "object_id";
    $clauses['orderby'] = "{$wpdb->terms}.term_order ASC";
    $clauses['orderby'] .= ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_name ASC";
  }

  return $clauses;
}
```

Another step that is needed is to use the [Simple Custom Post Order plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/). The plugin adds a `term_order` column to the terms table that the code uses to sort by. Drag and drop to change the terms order in products > attributes > brand. I actually had to move all of the terms around to get the order to sort correctly.

WooCommerce attributes do have a drag & drop functionality already, though. Perhaps it is possible to do something similar without that plugin.